# I have .NET Framework 4.0 installed but an app requires v2.0

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-framework, microsoft

I have .NET Framework 4.0 installed but an app requires v2.0.I can't find it even in the official MS site.Doesn't v4.0 include v2.0 libraries too? Aren't they compatible?
The 'Turn Windows Features trick' mentioned here

[Program installer requires .NET framework 3.5 but I have 4.8](https://superuser.com/questions/1575929/program-installer-requires-net-framework-3-5-but-i-have-4-8)

fails with 'Windows cannot find the files' when trying to downloading them.

Can I somehow fool the app to use v4 ?

Comment: .NET Framework versions are backwards compatible. .NET 2.0 cannot be installed on Windows 10.  .NET 4.0 cannot be installed either since .NET 4.8 is an in-place replacement for it and is built into Windows 21H2

Comment: Check with the people who wrote the app and ask them to fix it. Same situation for you in Windows 11.

Comment: You can try.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046089/force-an-application-to-run-under-specific-net-runtime-version